# Datastax Amazon EC2 AMI - Store the same data in two different location against configuration

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cassandra, datastax

I have launched Amazon Datastax AMI - EC2(m3.medium) instance to run cassandra with following storage configuration.

one root volume(instance store) - 8 GB. one EBS-IOPS volume - 50 GB.

I have mentioned data directory in cassandra.yaml as /mnt/cassandra/data.

With the above configuration, I can run cassandra.

My Problem is, When I create sample keyspace with table and its data,the data are stored in below two location

/var/lib/cassandra/data/ AND /mnt/cassandra/data

But in cassandra.yaml, I configured data directory should be on /mnt/cassandra/data.

Could any one please help me to find out "Why data are stored in two different location?". I would like to data must be present on my EBS volume only.

Thanks

Comment: I suspect you mounted both volumes `/var/lib/cassandra/data/ ` & `/mnt/cassandra/data` in a strange way. It seems like there is some mirroring between them. Are you sure there is no symbolic link somewhere around ?

Comment: Your are really genius. Yes there is symbolic link between the two location. Thanks.Please provide your answer below so that I can accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved, symbolic link issue between `/var/lib/cassandra/data/` and `/mnt/cassandra/data` folders